# How to Insert or Update table On base of Name value in Sqlite android

Tags: android, sqlite

```
public long createCountry(String code, String name, String continent,
     String region) {

     ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
     initialValues.put(KEY_PRODUCT_TYPE, code);
     initialValues.put(KEY_PRODUCT_NAME, name);
     initialValues.put(KEY_PRODUCT_QUANTITY, continent);
     initialValues.put(KEY_PRODCUT_COST, region);

     return mDb.insertWithOnConflict(SQLITE_TABLE, null, initialValues, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);

     }
```

this is for insert or Update function  but its taking new Row if name X is alredy present in table row i want it should Update Like suppose we have 3 Entry  whose name column value has X,Y,Z now Suppose i want call  again this function with name X then rest of value Should update not its should create another Column please help me where am doing wrong .

Answer (score 0):

There is no update-or-insert function.
You have to do this manually:

```java
public void createCountry(String code, String name, String continent, String region) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_PRODUCT_TYPE, code);
    values.put(KEY_PRODUCT_QUANTITY, continent);
    values.put(KEY_PRODCUT_COST, region);
    int updated = mDb.update(SQLITE_TABLE, values,
                    KEY_PRODUCT_NAME + " = ?",
                    new String[]{ name });
    if (updated == 0) {
        values.put(KEY_PRODUCT_NAME, name);
        mDb.insert(SQLITE_TABLE, null, values);
    }
}
```